# How to change the main font for the wiley-article class

Tags: fonts, fontspec, wiley-article

I'm writing an article and want to change the main font from "Lato" to "Strix Two Text". The code below is pre-defined (`wiley-article` template) and I'm struggling with the change.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% wiley-article.cls, v1.5, 2018/07/05
% Developed by Overleaf.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{wiley-article}[2018/07/05, v1.5]

%% Definitions for adding journal elements
\def\@jlogo{}
\def\@jname{}
\def\@jyear{}
\def\@jpages{}
\def\@jvolume{}
\def\@jwebsite{}

\def\@runningauthor{}
\def\@corraddress{}
\def\@corremail{}
\def\@presentaddress{}

\def\@papertype{original article}
\def\@paperfield{}
\def\@paperdoi{}
\def\@paperreceived{}
\def\@paperrevised{}
\def\@paperaccepted{}
\def\@papereditor{}

\newif\if@numrefs
\newif\if@alpharefs
\newif\if@amsrefs
\newif\if@blindreview
\newif\if@useserif
\newif\if@wiley@lineno

%% Add options for other journals here
\DeclareOption{jabr}{%
  \def\@jlogo{jabr-logo}%
  \def\@jname{J Appl Behav Res}%
  \def\@jwebsite{wileyonlinelibrary.com/journal/jabr}%
}

%% Options for bibliography style
\DeclareOption{num-refs}{
  \@numrefstrue
  \@alpharefsfalse
  \@amsrefsfalse
}
\DeclareOption{alpha-refs}{
  \@numrefsfalse
  \@alpharefstrue
  \@amsrefsfalse
}
\DeclareOption{ams-refs}{
  \@numrefsfalse
  \@alpharefsfalse
  \@amsrefstrue
}

%% Option for blind review
\DeclareOption{blind}{\@blindreviewtrue}

%% v1.3: Option for serif fonts
\DeclareOption{}{\@useseriftrue}

%% v1.4: Option for line numbers
\DeclareOption{lineno}{\@wiley@linenotrue}

%%
\DeclareOption{twocolumn}{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
  
%% v1.2: don't set any defaults
% \ExecuteOptions{num-refs}
\ProcessOptions\relax


\LoadClass[twoside]{article}

\RequirePackage[table]{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{ifpdf}
\RequirePackage{ifxetex}
\RequirePackage{ifluatex}
\RequirePackage{mathtools}
\RequirePackage{bm}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{tabularx}
\RequirePackage{textcase}
\RequirePackage{dashrule}
\RequirePackage{ragged2e}
\RequirePackage{authblk}
\RequirePackage[hyphens]{url}
\RequirePackage{soul}
\RequirePackage{xpatch}
\RequirePackage{afterpage}

\if@twocolumn
  \RequirePackage[switch]{lineno}
\else
  \RequirePackage{lineno}
\fi

\newif\ifxetexorluatex
\ifxetex
  \xetexorluatextrue
\else
  \ifluatex
    \xetexorluatextrue
  \else
    \xetexorluatexfalse
  \fi
\fi

\ifxetexorluatex
  \RequirePackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\else
  \ifpdf
    \RequirePackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
  \else
    \RequirePackage[framemethod=default]{mdframed}
    \RequirePackage{tikz}
  \fi
\fi

\RequirePackage{silence}
\WarningFilter{microtype}{tracking amount list}
\WarningFilter{latex}{Reference `mdf@pagelabel}

\ifxetexorluatex
  \RequirePackage{microtype}
  \RequirePackage[partial=upright]{unicode-math}
  \let\boldsymbol\symbf
  \if@useserif
    \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Termes}
    \setmathfont[Extension=.otf,BoldFont=*bold]{xits-math}
  \else
%     \RequirePackage[partial=upright]{unicode-math}
    \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{stix}
    \setmathfont{TeX Gyre DejaVu Math}
    \setmathfont[range={\int}]{Latin Modern Math}
    \setmathfont[range=\mathup/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}, Ligatures=TeX]{stix}
    \setmathfont[range=\mathit/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}, Ligatures=TeX]{Stix Italic}
    \setmathfont[range=\mathbfup/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}, Ligatures=TeX]{Stix Bold}
  \fi
  \setsansfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Stix}
\else
  \RequirePackage{microtype}
  \RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \if@useserif
    \RequirePackage{tgtermes}
    \RequirePackage{lato}
    \RequirePackage{stix}
  \else
    \RequirePackage[default]{lato}
    \IfFileExists{newtxsf.sty}{
      \RequirePackage[cmintegrals,nosymbolsc]{newtxsf}
    }{}
  \fi
  \ifpdf
  \SetTracking[spacing={500*,166,}]{encoding={*}}{80}
  \fi
\fi


\RequirePackage
 [paperwidth=171mm,paperheight=246mm,
  left=14.3mm,textwidth=142.4mm,lines=47,
  headsep=\baselineskip,headheight=16\p@,
  footskip=23\p@,columnsep=2em]
{geometry}

\RequirePackage{alphalph}
\newalphalph{\fnsymbolmult}[mult]{\@fnsymbol}{5}

\newcounter{authorfn}
\setcounter{authorfn}{1}
\newcommand{\authfn}[1]{%
  \fnsymbolmult{#1}%
}

\newcommand{\presentadd}[2][]{
  \ifx\empty\@presentaddress\else\appto{\@presentaddress}{\\}{}{}\fi
  \appto{\@presentaddress}{%
  \ifx\empty#1\else\textsuperscript{#1}\fi
  #2%
  }{}{}
}


%% These will be set by the \journal{} command
\newcommand{\jlogo}[1]{\def\@jlogo{#1}}
\newcommand{\jname}[1]{\def\@jname{#1}}
\newcommand{\jyear}[1]{\def\@jyear{#1}}
\newcommand{\jvolume}[1]{\def\@jvolume{#1}}
\newcommand{\jpages}[1]{\def\@jpages{#1}}
\newcommand{\jwebsite}[1]{\def\@jwebsite{#1}}


\newcommand{\runningauthor}[1]{\def\@runningauthor{#1}}
\newcommand{\corraddress}[1]{\def\@corraddress{#1}}
\newcommand{\corremail}[1]{\def\@corremail{#1}}

\newcommand{\paperdoi}[1]{\def\@paperdoi{#1}}
\newcommand{\paperreceived}[1]{\def\@paperreceived{#1}}
\newcommand{\paperrevised}[1]{\def\@paperrevised{#1}}
\newcommand{\paperaccepted}[1]{\def\@paperaccepted{#1}}
\newcommand{\papereditor}[1]{\def\@papereditor{#1}}
\newcommand{\papertype}[1]{\def\@papertype{#1}}
\newcommand{\paperfield}[1]{\def\@paperfield{#1}}

% normal font is 8pt/13pt
\RequirePackage{scrextend}
\changefontsizes[13\p@]{8\p@}

% sectional headings
\ifxetexorluatex
  \newcommand{\allcaps}[2][10.0]{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=#1}\MakeTextUppercase{#2}}
  %% Fake small caps
  \renewcommand{\textsc}[1]{{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=10.0,Scale=0.8}\MakeTextUppercase{#1}}}
\else
  \ifpdf
    \newcommand{\allcaps}[2][]{\textls*[#1]{\MakeTextUppercase{#2}}}
  \else
    \newcommand{\allcaps}[2][]{\MakeTextUppercase{#2}}
  \fi
\fi

\RequirePackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\fontsize{10pt}{13\p@}\bfseries}
  {\thesection}{1em}{\textmd{|}\quad\allcaps{#1}}

\newcommand{\backmatter}{%
  \titleformat{\section}
    {\fontsize{10pt}{13\p@}\bfseries}
    {}{0pt}{\allcaps{##1}}%
  \titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{ 1.5\baselineskip}{0.5\baselineskip}
}

\ifxetexorluatex
  \titleformat{name=\section,numberless}[block]
    {\fontsize{10pt}{13\p@}\bfseries\raggedright}
    {}{0pt}{\textsc{#1}}
\else
  \ifpdf
  \titleformat{name=\section,numberless}[block]
    {\fontsize{10pt}{13\p@}\scshape\bfseries\raggedright}
    {}{0pt}{\textls*{#1}}
  \else
  \titleformat{name=\section,numberless}[block]
    {\fontsize{10pt}{13\p@}\scshape\bfseries\raggedright}
    {}{0pt}{#1}
  \fi
\fi
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{1.5\baselineskip}{\baselineskip}
\titlespacing*{name=\section,numberless}{0pt}{1.5\baselineskip}{0.5\baselineskip}

\titleformat{\subsection}[block]
  {\fontsize{10pt}{13\p@}\bfseries\raggedright}
  {\thesubsection}{1em}{\textmd{|}\quad#1}

\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{1.5\baselineskip}{0.5\baselineskip}

\titleformat{\subsubsection}[block]
  {\fontsize{10pt}{13\p@}\bfseries\raggedright}
  {\thesubsubsection}{1em}{\textmd{|}\quad#1}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{1.5\baselineskip}{0.5\baselineskip}

\if@useserif
  \titleformat{\paragraph}[hang]
    {\fontsize{8.5\p@}{13\p@}\bfseries\selectfont\color{black!75}}
    {\theparagraph}{0pt}{#1}
  \titleformat{name=\paragraph,numberless}[hang]
    {\fontsize{8.5\p@}{13\p@}\bfseries\selectfont}
    {}{0pt}{#1}
  \titleformat{\subparagraph}[runin]
    {\normalsize\bfseries\selectfont\color{black!75}}
    {\thesubparagraph}{0pt}{#1}
\else
  \ifxetexorluatex
    \titleformat{\paragraph}[hang]
      {\fontsize{8.5\p@}{13\p@}\fontspec{Stix}\color{black!75}}
      {\theparagraph}{0pt}{#1}
    \titleformat{name=\paragraph,numberless}[hang]
      {\fontsize{8.5\p@}{13\p@}\fontspec{Stix}}
      {}{0pt}{#1}
    \titleformat{\subparagraph}[runin]
      {\normalsize\fontspec{Stix}\color{black!75}}
      {\thesubparagraph}{0pt}{#1}

  \else
    \titleformat{\paragraph}[hang]
      {\fontsize{8.5\p@}{13\p@}\fontseries{eb}\selectfont\color{black!75}}
      {\theparagraph}{0pt}{#1}
    \titleformat{name=\paragraph,numberless}[hang]
      {\fontsize{8.5\p@}{13\p@}\fontseries{eb}\selectfont}
      {}{0pt}{#1}
    \titleformat{\subparagraph}[runin]
      {\normalsize\fontseries{eb}\selectfont\color{black!75}}
      {\thesubparagraph}{0pt}{#1}
  \fi
\fi

\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pt}{\baselineskip}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\subparagraph}{0pt}{\baselineskip}{1em}


% Formatting of footer for first page
%% v1.4: can't use "real" footnotes anymore for twocolumn
\RequirePackage[flushmargin,bottom]{footmisc}
%   \def\blfootnote{\gdef\@thefnmark{}\@footnotetext}
%   \appto{\footnotelayout}{\fontsize{6\p@}{9\p@}\selectfont}
%   \let\oldfootnoterule\footnoterule
%   \renewcommand{\footnoterule}{\noindent\textcolor{black!50}{\rule{\textwidth}{0.5\p@}}\vskip2\p@}

\def\@fpfootnotes{}
\newcommand{\blfootnote}[1]{\appto{\@fpfootnotes}{#1\par}}


%% Headers
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrule}{}
\fancyhead[LO]{{\fontsize{7\p@}{13\p@}\selectfont%
  \setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{.5\p@}%
  \arrayrulecolor{black}%
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}X r | r @{}}%
  \textsc{\@runningauthor} & & \thepage\\\hline
  %& %\multicolumn{1}{r}{%
    %\raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[height=2.5em]{\@jlogo}}%
    %\quad%
    %\raisebox{0.25em}[0pt][0pt]{\colorbox{white}{\includegraphics[height=2em]{Wiley_Wordmark_black}}}} & \\
\end{tabularx}%
}}

\fancyhead[LE]{{\fontsize{7\p@}{13\p@}\selectfont%
  \setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{.5\p@}%
  \arrayrulecolor{black}%
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}l | l >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X @{}}%
  \thepage & & \textsc{\@runningauthor}\\\hline
%   \multicolumn{1}{@{}c}{} &
%   \raisebox{0.25em}[0pt][0pt]{\colorbox{white}{\includegraphics[height=2em]{Wiley_Wordmark_black}}}%
%   \quad%
%   \raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[height=2.5em]{\@jlogo}}\\
  \end{tabularx}%
}}

%% First page header + footer
\fancypagestyle{firstpage}{
%   \renewcommand{\footrule}{\hdashrule{\textwidth}{0.5\p@}{2\p@}\\[-2\p@]}

  \fancyhead[L]{\fontsize{7\p@}{13\p@}\selectfont%
  \setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{.5\p@}%
  \arrayrulecolor{black}%
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}l | l | X @{}}%
  \ifdefempty{\@paperreceived}
    {\multicolumn{3}{l}{}}
    {Received: \@paperreceived &
  Revised: \@paperrevised &
  Accepted: \@paperaccepted}
  \\\hline
  \ifdefempty{\@paperdoi}{}{\multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{DOI: \@paperdoi}}
  \end{tabularx}}

  \fancyfoot[L]{%\fontsize{7\p@}{10pt}\selectfont%
%   \setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{.5\p@}%
%   \arrayrulecolor{black}\raggedright%
%   This is an open access article under the terms of the Creative Commons Attribution License, which permits use, distribution and reproduction in any medium, provided the original work is properly cited.\\[3\p@]
%   \begingroup
  \fontsize{7\p@}{13\p@}\selectfont%
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}X  >{\centering\arraybackslash}X  r | r @{}}%
  \hline
  \ifdefempty{\@paperreceived}{& & & }{%
  \textit{\@jname}~\@jyear; \@jvolume: \@jpages &
  \@jwebsite &
  \textcopyright~\@jyear\space Wiley Periodicals, Inc. &
  }
  \thepage
  \end{tabularx}%
%   \endgroup
  }
}

% For adding notes about author contributions
\newcommand{\contrib}[2][]{%
  \blfootnote{\textsuperscript{#1}#2}%
}


% Author and affiliation fonts
\setcounter{Maxaffil}{1}
\renewcommand{\Authsep}{\quad|\quad}
\renewcommand{\Authand}{\quad|\quad}
\renewcommand{\Authands}{\quad|\quad}
\renewcommand{\Authfont}{\fontsize{12\p@}{20pt}\bfseries\raggedright}
\renewcommand{\Affilfont}{\fontsize{7\p@}{10pt}\selectfont\raggedright}
\renewcommand\AB@authnote[1]{\textsuperscript{#1}}
\patchcmd{\AB@affilsepx}{\\}{\\[3\p@]}{}{}

\patchcmd{\@author}{\AB@authlist\\[\affilsep]\AB@affillist}{\AB@authlist}{}{}

% % \AtBeginDocument{
%   \if@blindreview
%     \let\oldauthor\author
%     \let\oldaffil\affil
%     \renewcommand{\author}[2][]{\oldauthor{Author}}
%     \renewcommand{\affil}[2][]{\oldaffil{An affiliation}}
% % %     \def\AB@authors{Anonymous Authors}
% %     \def\AB@affillist{Anonymous Affiliations}
%   \fi
% % }

% Title
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
  \if@blindreview
    \def\AB@authlist{\Authfont Anonymous Authors}
    \def\AB@affillist{\Affilfont Anonymous Affiliations}
    \def\@runningauthor{Authors (Anon)}
    \def\@corraddress{Anonymous correspoundence}
    \def\@corremail{anon@example.com}
    \def\@presentaddress{Anonymous present address}
    \def\@fundinginfo{Anonymous funders}
  \fi
  \vspace*{\dimexpr 27\p@-2\baselineskip}%
  \noindent\begingroup%
  \setul{3\p@}{1\p@}%
  \if@useserif
    \bfseries%
  \else
    \ifxetexorluatex\fontspec{Stix}\else\fontseries{eb}\selectfont\fi%
  \fi
  {\fontsize{9\p@}{15\p@}\allcaps[\ifxetexorluatex 20\else 200\fi]{\ul{\@papertype}}}
  \ifdefempty{\@jlogo}{\rule{0pt}{2em}}{%
  \hfill%
%   \includegraphics[height=1.5em]{Wiley_Wordmark_black}%
%   \quad%
  \includegraphics[height=2em]{\@jlogo}}
  \\[2\p@]%
  {\fontsize{8\p@}{15\p@}%
  \ifxetexorluatex
    \addfontfeature{LetterSpace=20.0}\@paperfield%
  \else
    \ifpdf
    \textls*[150]{\@paperfield}%
    \else
    \@paperfield
    \fi
  \fi}
  \endgroup%
  \vskip13\p@%
  {\fontsize{18\p@}{23\p@}\bfseries\raggedright\@title\par}
  \vskip27\p@%
  \noindent\begin{minipage}{0.8\textwidth}\@author\end{minipage}%
  \vskip21\p@%
  \thispagestyle{firstpage}
}

% Affiliation + other metadata
\newcommand{\wiley@affilmetadata}{%
  \AB@affillist\par%
  \vskip10pt%
  \textbf{Correspondence}\\
  \@corraddress\\
  Email: \@corremail\par
  \ifx\empty\@presentaddress
  \else%
    \vskip10pt%
    \textbf{Present address}\\
    \@presentaddress\par
  \fi%
  \vskip10pt%
  \ifdefempty{\@papereditor}{}
  {\vskip10pt Editor: \@papereditor\par}
}

%% Abbreviations in the footnote
\newcommand{\abbrevs}[1]{\blfootnote{\textbf{Abbreviations:} #1\\[-3\p@]}}

%% Abstract and affiliation in the margin
\RequirePackage{changepage}
\RequirePackage{environ}
\RequirePackage{marginnote}
\reversemarginpar
\newlength{\wiley@affilmetadataheight}
\newlength{\wiley@abstractheight}
\NewEnviron{wiley@abstract}{%
  \newcommand{\keywords}[1]{%
    \vskip8\p@%
    \noindent{\bfseries\fontsize{7\p@}{13\p@}\allcaps[\ifxetexorluatex 20\else 200\fi]{keywords}\par}
    \noindent{\raggedright\fontsize{8\p@}{13\p@}\selectfont ##1\par}
  }%
  \strictpagecheck%
  \begin{adjustwidth*}{\dimexpr 35mm-6.5\p@}{}%
  \setlength{\marginparsep}{-30mm}%
  \setlength{\marginparwidth}{30mm}%
  %% Measure the height of the affil metadata in the sidebar
  \settototalheight{\wiley@affilmetadataheight}{\parbox{\marginparwidth}{\wiley@affilmetadata}}%
  \newsavebox{\wiley@abstractbox}%
  %% Save the abstract text in a box
  \savebox{\wiley@abstractbox}{%
    \parbox{\linewidth}{%
    \begin{mdframed}[font=\fontsize{9\p@}{15\p@}\selectfont,
      topline=false,bottomline=false,
      leftline=true,rightline=false,
      backgroundcolor=black!10,
      middlelinewidth=6\p@,middlelinecolor=white,
      outerlinewidth=0.5\p@]
      \BODY
    \end{mdframed}}%
  }%
  \settototalheight{\wiley@abstractheight}{\usebox{\wiley@abstractbox}}%
  \marginnote{\wiley@affilmetadata}%
  \begin{mdframed}[font=\fontsize{9\p@}{15\p@}\selectfont,
  topline=false,bottomline=false,
  leftline=true,rightline=false,
  backgroundcolor=black!10,
  middlelinewidth=6\p@,middlelinecolor=white,
  outerlinewidth=0.5\p@]%
  %% v1.5: number the abstract lines as well
  \if@wiley@lineno
    \internallinenumbers\rightlinenumbers\resetlinenumber%
  \fi%
  \BODY%
  \end{mdframed}%
  %% If the affildata is taller than the abstract, add vskip
  \ifdimgreater
    {\wiley@affilmetadataheight}
    {\wiley@abstractheight}
    {\vskip\dimexpr\wiley@affilmetadataheight-\wiley@abstractheight+1.5\baselineskip\relax}
    {\vskip1.5\baselineskip}
}[\end{adjustwidth*}]%

\renewcommand{\abstract}{\wiley@abstract}
\renewcommand{\endabstract}{\endwiley@abstract}

\newcommand{\thefpfootnotes}{%
  \noindent\textcolor{black!50}{\rule{\textwidth}{0.5\p@}}\\
  {\fontsize{6\p@}{9\p@}\selectfont
  \@fpfootnotes}
}

%% v1.4: Add two-column mode 
\NewEnviron{frontmatter}{%
  \if@twocolumn
    \let\oldclearpage\clearpage
    \let\clearpage\relax
    \ifdefvoid{\@fpfootnotes}{}{%
      \begin{figure*}[b!]
      \thefpfootnotes
      \end{figure*}
    }  
    \twocolumn[\@twocolumnfalse\setlength\parindent{2em}\BODY]
    \let\clearpage\oldclearpage
  \else
    \BODY
  \fi%
}

% v1.4: Add line numbers too
\if@wiley@lineno
  \AfterEndEnvironment{frontmatter}{\linenumbers}
  \if@twocolumn\else
    \AfterEndEnvironment{abstract}{\linenumbers}  
  \fi
\fi

\if@twocolumn\else
  \appto{\maketitle}{%
    \ifdefvoid{\@fpfootnotes}{}{%
      \begin{figure*}[b!]
      \thefpfootnotes
      \end{figure*}
    }  
  }
\fi

% quotes and epigraphs
\RequirePackage{quoting}
\quotingsetup{vskip=\baselineskip,indentfirst=false,font={itshape,RaggedRight,normalsize},leftmargin=26\p@,rightmargin=26\p@}

\renewenvironment{quote}{\begin{quoting}}{\end{quoting}}

\renewenvironment{quotation}{\begin{quoting}}{\end{quoting}}

\newenvironment{epigraph}[1]
{\begin{quoting}\def\@quotesource{#1}}
{\par\hfill\@quotesource\end{quoting}}

\newenvironment{pullquote}
{\begin{quoting}[vskip=\dimexpr 39\p@-23\p@\relax,leftmargin=12\p@,rightmargin=12\p@,font+={raggedright},begintext={\fontsize{18\p@}{23\p@}\selectfont\color{black!50}}]}
{\end{quoting}}

% Enum/itemized
\RequirePackage[inline]{enumitem}
\setlist{nosep,font=\bfseries,leftmargin=*,align=left}
\setlist[1]{topsep=\baselineskip,leftmargin=\parindent,labelsep=*,labelwidth=*}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label={\alph*.},}

% Space above/below equations
\g@addto@macro\normalsize{%
  \setlength\abovedisplayskip{\baselineskip}%
  \setlength\belowdisplayskip{\baselineskip}%
  \setlength\abovedisplayshortskip{\baselineskip}%
  \setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{\baselineskip}%
}

% All the popular math environments
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}

\newenvironment{proof}[1][Proof]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}]}{\end{trivlist}}
\newenvironment{definition}[1][Definition]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}]}{\end{trivlist}}
\newenvironment{example}[1][Example]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}]}{\end{trivlist}}
\newenvironment{remark}[1][Remark]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}]}{\end{trivlist}}


\newcommand{\qed}{\nobreak \ifvmode \relax \else
      \ifdim\lastskip<1.5em \hskip-\lastskip
      \hskip1.5em plus0em minus0.5em \fi \nobreak
      \vrule height0.75em width0.5em depth0.25em\fi}

% Captions
\RequirePackage[tableposition=top]{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFont{captionfont}{\fontsize{8\p@}{11\p@}\selectfont}
\DeclareCaptionFont{boxcaption}{\fontsize{9\p@}{13\p@}\selectfont}
\ifxetexorluatex
  \DeclareCaptionFont{heavy}{\fontspec{Stix}}
  \DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{allcaps}{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=15.0}{\MakeTextUppercase{#1}~#2}}
\else
  \DeclareCaptionFont{heavy}{\fontseries{eb}}
  \ifpdf
  \DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{allcaps}{\textls[150]{\MakeTextUppercase{#1}~#2}}
  \else
  \DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{allcaps}{\MakeTextUppercase{#1}~#2}
  \fi
\fi
\if@useserif
  \captionsetup*{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false,font=captionfont,labelformat=allcaps,labelfont={bf},labelsep=quad}
\else
  \captionsetup*{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false,font=captionfont,labelformat=allcaps,labelfont={heavy},labelsep=quad}
\fi
\captionsetup*[table]{skip=0.5ex}

% Tables
\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{%
  \fontsize{9.5\p@}{9.5\p@}\selectfont%
  \rowcolors*{3}{black!10}{}%
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.7}%
  \arrayrulecolor{black!20}%
  \setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1\p@}%
}

\RequirePackage{threeparttable}
\renewcommand{\TPTnoteSettings}{\leftmargin=0pt}
\newcommand{\headrow}{\rowcolor{black!20}}
\newcommand{\thead}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries #1\rule[-1.2ex]{0pt}{2em}}}

%% Boxes!
\RequirePackage{stfloats}
\RequirePackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[placement=bt,name=box]{featurebox}
\captionsetup*[featurebox]{skip=1em,labelformat={default},font={heavy,boxcaption},labelfont={sc,color=black!75}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{featurebox}{%
  \setlist*{topsep=0pt}%
}
\apptocmd{\featurebox}{%
  \begin{mdframed}[linewidth=5\p@,linecolor=black!20,
  innerleftmargin=12\p@,innerrightmargin=12\p@,
  innertopmargin=12\p@,innerbottommargin=12\p@]
}{}{}
\pretocmd{\endfeaturebox}{\end{mdframed}}{}{}


% Skips for floats
\setlength{\floatsep}{1.5\baselineskip}
\setlength{\intextsep}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{1.5\baselineskip}

% The endnotes
\RequirePackage{enotez}
\newlist{enotezlist}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[enotezlist,1]{leftmargin=*,label=\arabic*,labelsep=0.25em,itemsep=0pt,topsep=0.5\baselineskip}
\EditInstance{enotez-list}{itemize}
{list-type=enotezlist}
\setenotez{list-name={endnotes},list-style=itemize}
\EditInstance{enotez-list}{itemize}{
  format=\fontsize{7.5\p@}{10.5\p@}\selectfont,
  number = \textsuperscript{#1}
}

% References
\if@numrefs
  \RequirePackage[numbers]{natbib}
  \bibliographystyle{vancouver-authoryear}
\fi
\if@alpharefs
    \RequirePackage{natbib}
    \bibliographystyle{rss}
\fi
\if@amsrefs
  \RequirePackage{amsrefs}
  \let\citep\cite
  \let\citet\ocite
  \renewcommand{\biblistfont}{\fontsize{7.5\p@}{7.5\p@}\selectfont}
\fi

\AtBeginDocument{
  \@ifpackageloaded{natbib}{
    \setlength{\bibhang}{1.5em}
    \renewcommand{\bibfont}{\fontsize{7.5\p@}{10.5\p@}\selectfont}
    \renewcommand{\refname}{References}
    \renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
  }{}

  \@ifpackageloaded{amsrefs}{
    \renewcommand{\biblistfont}{\fontsize{7.5\p@}{10.5\p@}\selectfont}
    \renewcommand{\refname}{References}
    \renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
  }{}
}

% Author biography
\RequirePackage{lettrine}
\newenvironment{biography}[2][]
{\begin{mdframed}
  [linewidth=0.5\p@,skipabove=1.5\baselineskip,%nobreak,
    innerleftmargin=6\p@,innerrightmargin=6\p@,
    innertopmargin=6\p@,innerbottommargin=6\p@]
  \ifstrequal{#1}{}{}
  {\lettrine[image,lines=5,findent=1em,nindent=0pt]{#1}{}}%
  {\bfseries\scshape #2}}
{\end{mdframed}}

\newcommand{\otherinfo}[2][]{%
  \backmatter%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{suppinfo}
  {\section{Supporting Information}
  Additional Supporting Information may be found online in the supporting information for this article.}
  {}

  \begin{mdframed}
  [linewidth=1\p@,linecolor=black!40,nobreak,
    innerleftmargin=12\p@,innerrightmargin=12\p@,
    innertopmargin=12\p@,innerbottommargin=12\p@,
    skipabove=\baselineskip]
  \textbf{How to cite this article:} #2
  \end{mdframed}
}

\newenvironment{graphicalabstract}[1]{%
  \backmatter
  \section{graphical abstract}
  \lettrine[image,lines=10,findent=1em,nindent=0pt]{#1}{}%
}{}

% Here we go!
\normalsize
\pagestyle{fancy}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \robustify{\ref}
  \robustify{\cite}
  \ifdef{\citep}{\robustify{\citep}}{}
  \ifdef{\citet}{\robustify{\citet}}{}
}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgfplotsset{/pgf/number format/use comma}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} 
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig,lipsum,booktabs}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage[fontspec]
```

Comment: Note, if you're writing an article and has been asked to use a specific template, then you don't change the template or its design. It is really annoying being in the receiving end of such changes.

Comment: Publisher classes like Wiley's _by design_ aim to remove choice from the author and enforce the publisher style. Even if it is easy to change, changing it may delay or even prevent publication, depending on the publisher's policies.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. Its just for an exam (not a publication) and I just want to change the font. It´s an open Overleaf template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't just load the stix2 package, because you'll get a "too many symbols fonts declared error".

It looks like a previous version of that document class had a "serif" option, but they removed it by removing its name. However, a small change to the `.cls` would restore it.

Copy the `.cls` file to the folder with your .`tex` if need be (or upload it to separately to Overleaf in that folder; I don't know how Overleaf works as I've never used it), so you're just editing a local copy of the file.

Look for line 65, which reads:

```
\DeclareOption{}{\@useseriftrue}
```

Change it to:

```
\DeclareOption{serif}{\@useseriftrue}
```

Now, use that option when you load the class in your `.tex` file:

```
\documentclass[serif]{wiley-article}
```

That by itself would get you close: it then uses Stix General as its main font and Stix Math as its math font. But if you specifically want stix2 instead, changing things to the serif option reduces already the number of symbols fonts it uses, so you have enough "left" to load stix2, and you can put in your document's preamble:

```
\usepackage{stix2}
```

And then it should work.

Or for "stix too", which is basically the same, just for the regular text, and not the math:

```
\usepackage{stickstootext}
```

[image]